# JavaScript / SharePoint - Force file download

Tags: javascript, file, sharepoint

**SITUATION**:

I have a file that has to be opened by an unknown number of users on my SharePoint site. It's an InfoPath form, which is automatically opened by the browser per the MIME Types settings. My organization uses IE, and since I'm a 'node' of the organization, I can't access headers or .htaccess files. It's also an intranet with TONS of security settings, many of which have been changed so often on individual computers it's impossible to account for them.

**ATTEMPTS**:

I've tried JavaScript `target='_blank'`, and `execCommand`. Unfortunately neither of them work and I'm at my wits end! The Infopath form is **not** browser-enabled, and the document library is set to open in Client Program, yet most people cannot open the form.

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way using JavaScript or a similar Client-side language to prompt that 'Open' box? Unless someone knows of a way to configure it to always prompt instead of automatically open in the browser, that is.

Comment: "TONS of security settings, many of which have been changed so often on individual computers it's _impossible to account for them_" - now /that/ is an oxymoron. Doesn't sound very secure.

Comment: I suppose unpredictability is more secure than uniformity, from the aspect of the hacker. That isn't our security policy; it's more of 'the less the user can do, the less a hacker can do' in a paraphrased and slightly sarcastic way. The Group Policy settings are constantly being updated, and not every computer gets the updates / is plugged into the network. With 3.5k users, it's not as easy as you'd think.

Comment: The more variety there is, the more vectors there are open to attack.

Comment: We found an easier solution to a problem that wasn't entirely known. Firefox must not have the same settings as IE as far as file handling goes, and as long as Infopath is intalled on the computer it opens fine with IE. Being that IE is our required browser, Firefox isn't a situation we need to prepare for. Though I'm still going to look into this for future problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soultion is to really work with it on the server. The Content-disposition header needs to be set. [MS KB Aticle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519)

Teh sharepoint admin should be able to set the setting in the General Settings and set `Browser File Handling` to strict.

Comment: Say we need to have lots of files to be downloaded with the same file ext (.xml). Will the * wildcard work for the Content-Disposition?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used InfoPath before, but it seems like this problem might be related to browser file handling settings.

By default, browser file handling is set to strict at the web-app level (as it should be). However, this can be overridden at the document library level and as far as I know, it's a hidden setting (at least I've never seen it in the UI), so you'll need to use SharePoint Manager or PowerShell to view/change it.

If you need to, you can use PS to add exceptions to this setting at the web-app level. Not sure if you can do the same at the doclib level.

Comment: I can't directly access our server with a command-line. I don't really have control over it, and those who do have control over it would see that as an attack or have security that makes Fort Knox look like a 7-11.

Comment: Sounds like a madhouse :P Well, what you're proposing technically increases security for users since automatically opening things in the browser can lead to XSS attacks... so maybe you'll be able to convince them :D Would you be able to get a sysadmin to at least tell you what the current doclib setting is?